Is Monotone QSAT PSPACE Complete?
I've seen that "Monotone" is given a few different definitions w.r.t. SAT, but I'm interested in the more common definition: The SAT problem, where each clause contains only unnegated variables or only negated variables.
Monotone SAT is NP-complete, as various papers such as On simplified NP-complete variants of Monotone 3-Sat build on, by further tightening the requirements.
It seems that the quantified version of NP-complete problems tend to be PSPACE complete, however I've been unable to find a reference to this claim that holds in general.
I'm mostly interested in the case of this specific problem; is Monotone QSAT PSPACE complete?

I think this is immediate from the quantitied Schaefer dichotomy theorem; see Theorem 6.3 in Hubie Chen's exposition
